# Can I use a React app as a component on a static HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, build

I'm new to React and JS, and working with [react-csv-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv-viewer).

It works as expected and I can build and deploy it on a local server. But I do not require this, I just want to integrate the app as a component of a static HTML page.

I've tried following the process listed on the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) for this, but I have trouble understanding the build process and how can I achieve this.

All I wish to achieve is to be able to use `<CsvViewer />` provided by the author, possibly like this

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CsvViewer />, rootElement);
```

and get the viewer app rendered at my HTML file, without building and deploying the viewer app on a (local) server.

Will appreciate any help or hints in this regard.

Comment: It's just a component.  You import it and embed it like any other React component.  Following the tutorial, just drop it in the `return` of the `render` in your JSX.

Answer (score 2):

You can add React as it was shown in the tutorial you linked.  The downside is that, you can't use JSX syntax (as it should be converted to JS during build time as it's not recognized by browsers as so).

Here is a post explaining how you can do so without transpilaton steps.

https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/post/react-without-a-build-step

Alias `React.createElement`, and call it to create components.
e.g.)

```js
const h = createElement // convenient alias

// Instead of
<div className="foo" />

// create an element like so
h("div", { className: "foo" })
```

For more info on how that works, check out the official documentation.
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects

But I really doubt anyone writes React code that way without a transpilation step in real life.

Would creating a separate site/page with React be a problem by chance?  You can check out [ParcelJS](https://parceljs.org/) to easily create a React site if you aren't familiar with transpilation.

Comment: I do not wish to create a separate page, as this is supposed to add a small widget-like, functionality to a page which already exists and is rendered independently.

Comment: @bambi022 `CsvViewer` is a CJS module, which needs `require`. You can find a way to use `require` on the browser but `CsvViewer` isn't necessarily built to be used directly on the browser. If you need a starting point with React, try this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-without-jsx-i605i) I created.